# JENKINS: multiple shared jenkinsfiles

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am a bit new with Jenkins and I would like to have some shared Jenkinsfiles. For example by technology: `jenkinsfile_java, jenkinsfile_php,  etc.`

Inside each project, a jenkinsfile which call the jenkinsfile_java passing the url of the scm and the branch for example.

I'm reading during hours and my head is going to explode, I don't understand nothing and I'm very confused. Could someone help with this? I would be very grateful.

Many thanks for all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by using a Shared Libary. In your particular case this Shared Libary should be project with a `var/` directory that contains files `java.groovy`, `php.groovy`, etc. From your `Jenkinsfile` inside the project you can then include the pipeline that you defined in the shared library.

The Jenkins manual explains this in more detail, especially the section on defining your own DSL: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-a-more-structured-dsl

Comment: Many thanks Wilco, finally i did it!, only with defining a call in the groovy script and in the Jenkinsfile of each project 2 lanes: @Library('jenkinsfile_java') _
pipeline_java()